# Magento - look up products created in the last hour

Tags: magento, product, datecreated

I'm trying to look up products created in the last hour.

I'm able to sort products by created date like so:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc');
```

But I'd like to filter by created_at. I've tried replacing the last line of the above block with `addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('gteq' =>$time));`, which I think must be right, but I can't find the right format for `$time`.

Am I on the right track here, and if so, what format should I be feeding `$time` in with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the MySQL timestamp format.
The following code worked for me:

```
$time = "2013-02-06 09:32:23"; // 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss'

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc')
->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('gteq' =>$time));
```

You can quite easily find the format of a given attribute, by simple echoing it to your screen.
For example:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc');

exit($collection->getFirstItem()->getData('created_at');
```

The output for that was *2013-02-06 09:32:23* (on my environment)

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! That's a 100% fix. I don't know why I was struggling with that, it looks so obvious now.

Comment: "Now that I've figured it out, it looks so obvious" is my motto when working with Magento. Don't feel too bad about it.